# Setting a job schedule for pgagent in linux through command line

Tags: linux, postgresql, job-scheduling, pgagent

I cannot set a job schedule for pgagent in linux shell. However, I can do that in pgAdmin GUI, but not in command line. Has anybody ever done that in linux command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an INSERT or UPDATE on the postgres-database, in schema pgagent.

```
SELECT * FROM pg_tables WHERE schemaname = 'pgagent';
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Could you give more details on how I can solve my problem? What should I insert into pg_tables or any other table in order to configure job task for pg_agent?

Comment: Use the tables you get from pg_tables to construct a new job for pgagent. pg_tables just shows the tables you need, nothing else.

Comment: I issued select commands to see what is in those tables, but I was told that such tables don't exist. Should I create those tables myself and what is their structure should be?

Comment: If these tables don't exist in the database postgres, you didn't install pgagent properly. Don't create these tables manually, just take the installer script from pgagent to install everything. Including functions, triggers, etc.